# Libcurl call to get oAuth token

Tags: c++, rest, api, curl, libcurl

I am working on a workflow which requires me to call a service with an OTP. The service then returns an OAuth token to me.

I am new to C++ and REST APIs. I haven't really written any code yet, but I was hoping to get a high level idea of how this call would work, before I could proceed.

I will be using a wrapper around libcurl.

I know I can get the token using GET. Can I use POST to send OTP and get the token in the same call?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Is there a site where I could test rest calls?

Comment: "*Can I use POST to send OTP and get the token in the same call?*" - that is entirely dependent on the particular REST API you are accessing. Every site's REST implementation is different. What does its documentation say about the output of the POST request? "*Is there a site where I could test rest calls?*" - Maybe. Since every site's REST implementation is different. some sites do provide sandboxes and test pages, while others only document what sample requests look like and you would have to mimic them manually in your own code/system.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for replying. Eventually I will have access the REST API of a custom site which returns the token. Right now I am testing using https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

O am trying to figure out the CURL post way to get stuff from this site.